# Including a framework without embedding it in the app bundle

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks

I'm still not 100% sure with the framework linking process, but from what I've seen here before nobody has asked a similar question, perhaps because this could be a silly question, but I'll give it a go anyway.

In my current X-Code project, I'm using a custom framework, say example.framework. At the moment, as far as I'm aware of, in order for the program to function with the framework, I need to have it either in /Library/Frameworks, or I need to have it copied into the bundle resources in the build phase.

Would anybody know about adding a framework to a project in a way that it gets compiled into the executable, so I don't have to include the raw framework with the app? I'd rather not share the whole framework...

Thank you in advance! Any suggestions are also welcome!

Comment: Sounds like what you really need to link against is a static library. Is that an option for you? "Framework" is basically a fancy name for dynamic library.

Comment: Sure, I guess so. The only issue is that the framework also uses a bundle within it. Ideally, I'd like to compile the bundle's executable, and the framework's executable, into my executable, instead of including both the framework and bundle, with legible headers... Would you have any advice on where to start with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Mac OS X framework is basically a shared library, meaning it's a separate binary.

Basically, when your main executable is launched, the OS will load the framework/dylib into memory, and map the symbols, so your main executable can access them.

Note that a framework/dylib (bundled into the application or not), does not need to contain the header files, as those are only needed at compilation time.

With Xcode, you can actually decide whether or not to include the header files, when you are copying the framework to its installation directory (see your build phases).

[image]

If you don't copy header files, people won't be able to use your framework/dylib (unless they reverse-engineer it, of course).

If you still think a framework is not suitable for your needs, you may want to create a static library instead.

A static library is a separate object file (usually .a) that is «included» with your final binary, at link time.

This way, you only have a single binary file, containing the code from the library and from your project.